# How to put a URL with a regular expression in Spring Java based configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

In a Spring Security XML configuration file, I have something like

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="\A/categories/\d+/items/admin\Z" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

How to handle the regular expression if I convert the above into a Java based configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `regexMatchers` method on `HttpSecurity`:

```java
public class SpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .regexMatchers("\A/categories/\d+/items/admin\").hasRole("USER");
    }
}
```