# How to make a regex pattern for a link with paramater? Spring Security 3.2.x

Tags: java, regex, url, spring-security

I'm trying to allow a link with parameter in Spring Security.

The link in the browser looks like this:

```
http://myapp.com/activateAccount/?token=2b7bneehdmra1b35
```

I read that antMatchers() don't work with such links. So instead I want to use regexMatchers().

My current code looks like this:

```
.regexMatchers("\\A\\/activateAccount\\/\\?token=.*\\Z").permitAll()
```

Does anyone how to build a valid pattern for this kind of link?

Any kind of advice will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to double escape `?` by doing:

```
"\\A\\/activateAccount\\/\\\\?token=.*\\Z"
                           ^--- Here
```

Since `?` is a regex special character you need to escape it by using `\?`, so in java you need `\\\\?`

Btw, I assume that your regex is good for SpringSecurity, I'm just pointing what is the error on your regex. You might consider using this code instead:

```
.regexMatchers("\\/activateAccount\\/\\\\?token=.*$").permitAll()
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but spring still doesn't recognize the pattern and the link doesn't go through.

Comment: @eslaron have you checked this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130376/how-to-put-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-spring-java-based-configuration?

Comment: I checked it and eclipse tells me that there are unescaped characters.