# Spring Security antMatchers Regex

Tags: regex, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I already have antmatchers() in my spring security config that uses a wildcard . I need to filter out the "forms" from this wildcard.
Here is my original code :

```
    .antMatchers("/api/keepSessionAlive").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/api/users/**").authenticated()
```

I tried to change the wildcard to a regex as you can see below and it didn't work for me :

```
   .antMatchers("/api/users/(?!forms).*").authenticated()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide examples of some urls you would like to match. Just saying it doesn't work isn't enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a URL with a regular expression in Spring Java based configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130376/how-to-put-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-spring-java-based-configuration)

Comment: If you insist to use `antMatchers`, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649649/antmatchers-spring-security-pattern-with-changeable-url-user-id, but it is made for a more specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the "/users/forms" filter before "/users/**" antMatchers

```
.antMatchers("/api/keepSessionAlive").authenticated()
.antMatchers("/api/users/forms/**").authenticated() 
.antMatchers("/api/users/**").authenticated()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an antmatcher for **"form"** before others and keep it as permit-all as follows:

```
.antMatchers("/api/users/form").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/keepSessionAlive").authenticated()
.antMatchers("/api/users/forms/**").authenticated() 
.antMatchers("/api/users/**").authenticated()
```

Hope this helps.